# Can PartitionKey be queried with StartsWith?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

In Azure Table Storage, is it possible to query PartitionKey with a StartsWith or some other operator e.g. Contains, etc.

I know I can do this with RowKeys but is it possible to do it with PartitionKeys?

A follow up question is: even if it's doable, is it advisable? Should PartitionKey always be an exact match -- say, for performance reasons?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, the good news is that you CAN do partial matches, and you will get "good" performance as long as the number of partitions being hit is small. If you have lots of partition keys, performance will suffer.

I could try to summarize an excellent write-up on this, but it's already written, so if you point your browser to the following link, you should learn all there is to know about partitions, rowkeys, and expected performaces:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh508997.aspx

Comment: This answer is incorrect! You can't do partial searches with Azure Tables using operators like StartsWith or Contains.

Comment: We prefer answers here without voting requests please - posts are best attracting +/- votes organically. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

Here's an example using the `GreaterThanOrEqual` and `LessThan` operators, as an extension on the target column name.

The filter combines two parts:

- anything greater than or equal to your startsWith prefix,
- increment the last character of your prefix and find anything less than this.

For example, `startsWith` prefix "CAR" will prepare something like `s >= "CAR" && s < "CAS"`.

```
    public static string GetStartsWithFilter(this string columnName, string startsWith)
    {
        var length = startsWith.Length - 1;
        var nextChar = startsWith[length] + 1;

        var startWithEnd = startsWith.Substring(0, length) + (char)nextChar;
        var filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(columnName, QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, startsWith),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(columnName, QueryComparisons.LessThan, startWithEnd));

        return filter;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var query = new TableQuery<MyTableEntity>().Where(myColumnName.GetStartsWithFilter(prefix));
```

Based on [Alexandre B's blog post](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/azure-table-storage-using-startswith-to-filter-on-rowkeys/)

Comment: You can get rid of the dependency on the **WindowsAzure.Storage** NuGet package by just constructing the query as a string: `return $"({columnName} ge '{startsWith}') and ({columnName} lt '{startsWithEnd}')";`

Answer (score 3):

> In Azure Table Storage, is it possible to query PartitionKey with a
>   StartsWith or some other operator e.g. Contains, etc.

No, it is not possible to do queries using StartsWith or Contains query operator with Azure Tables. To simulate `StartsWith`, you would need to use the combination of `Greater Than Equal To` and `Less Than` operators. You can't use `Contains` operator. What you would need to do is first fetch all the data on the client side and then use `Contains` to filter the data on the client side only.

For a list of supported query operators, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx.

> I know I can do this with RowKeys but is it possible to do it with
>   PartitionKeys?

I don't think it is possible. I'm curious to know why you're saying this.

> A follow up question is: even if it's doable, is it advisable? Should
>   PartitionKey always be an exact match -- say, for performance reasons?

I would highly recommend reading this excellent guide for this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/.