# `endsWith` and `startsWith` for Azure Table Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Table Storage on CosmosDB through Node.js. I figured out a hack using greater than and less than to give `startsWith` functionality.

On the other hand, I still need `endsWith` functionality and can't find a way to make it work. It might be one of those cases where I have to pull in all partition or row keys and then do the string search myself.

I noticed Azure Table has the same query format as odata and in this document for `$filter`, I'm seeing an `endsWith` command listed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh169248(v=nav.90)

Is there an `endsWith` command available or instead, is there a way to query all the partition or row keys and do the search myself?

Comment: To select the PrimaryKey and RowKeys only, use: `new TableQuery().select('PartitionKey', 'RowKey')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an endsWith command available or instead, is there a way to
>   query all the partition or row keys and do the search myself?

Unfortunately both `startsWith` and `endsWith` commands are not available in Azure Table Storage. For `startsWith`, I am guessing you implemented a hack similar to the solution outlined here: [Can PartitionKey be queried with StartsWith?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804458/can-partitionkey-be-queried-with-startswith).

However no such hack is available for `endsWith`. One possibility though will be to store another entity where you reverse the `PartitionKey` (or `RowKey`) and then apply `startsWith` hack. For example, your `PartitionKey` is `abcdef` and you need to find the entities that ends with `ef`, you could store another entity with `PartitionKey` as `fedcba` and then to apply the startsWith hack using `fe` (again reversing the string you're searching for).

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yeah, that's not something I'd want to manage. I will just query for the entire list of them. There won't be more than 100 or so anyway. Nothing too strenuous for JavaScript to handle.

Comment: For 100 entities, yes the solution is an overkill. You could this filtering on the client side only.